# Access outside array created in one foreach loop in a new foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, scope

It must be simple - but I can't figure it out. I have created an `array` in a `foreach` loop - like this:

```
foreach ($fixturesarray as $value) { 
    if ($i++ % 9 == 3) { 
        $hometeamarray[] = $value; 
    }
}
```

and it works fine... Then I would like to use the array (`$hometeamarray`) in another `foreach` loop - like this:

```
foreach ($xmlteams->children() as $output) { 
    if (in_array($output->OPPONENT, $hometeamarray)) { 
        $result[] = (string) $output->ALIGNED; 
    }
}
```

I need to check each value in `$hometeamarray` in the node of the XML-file called OPPONENT and then replace them with the node of the XML-file called ALIGNED. It all goes very well except that I can't access the `$hometeamarray` in the second foreach loop???

Comment: *I can't access the $hometeamarray* why do you think do ?

Comment: I assume you have `$hometeamarry` defined before the first foreach loop? if not, just add `$hometeamarray = array();` before the first loop and it should work

Comment: `var_dump($hometeamarray)` just before your second `foreach`, if it's `null` then it's either not being populated, or you have an issue elsewhere (for example if your second `foreach` is running within a closure). You should really initialise your `$hometeamarray` before your first `foreach`, then if it's an empty array you know it's the former, else the latter

Comment: I now have added `$hometeamarray = array();` before the first loop... but I receive no output at all - not even an empty array. Hmmm?

Comment: The output of `var_dump($hometeamarray)` is `array(72) { [0]=> string(51) "Novo Nordisk " [1]=> string(49) "PlayStation FC " etc. }` so it's populated...  :)

Comment: `string(51) "Novo Nordisk "`   - it contains many invisible symbols, i think

Comment: I don't know what you mean by invisible symbols?

Comment: length of `"Novo Nordisk "` is 13 chars. print_r write 51. Where 38 chars ?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would initialize the `array` before the cycle, like:

```
$hometeamarray = array();
foreach ($fixturesarray as $value) { 
    if ($i++ % 9 == 3) { 
        $hometeamarray[] = $value; 
    }
}
```

To avoid issues when `$fixturesarray` is empty.

Now, the reason you are not able to reach `$hometeamarray` can be various. You need to make sure that the second cycle is executed AFTER the first one. Also, you need to make sure `$hometeamarray` is not outside of scope in the second cycle. `var_dump`-ing it you should see whether that's your problem. Finally make sure you have `children` in `$xmlteams` and that they have an `OPPONENT` member and whether that can be found in `$hometeamarray`.

Comment: In my php page it comes in the order so the first foreach loop is placed above the second loop. A `var_dump`-ing test between the two foreach loops gave this result: `array(72) { [0]=> string(51) "Novo Nordisk" [1]=> string(49) "PlayStation FC" etc. }` and my XML-file is good as well.

Comment: and I have tested with another array made by hand - and with this it works... all this just to identify the problem...

Comment: @McClaud what are the $output->OPPONENT values you have and what is inside $hometeamarray before you enter that loop?

Comment: The $output->OPPONENT contains matching values (in a different order) to the ones inside $hometeamarray. Basicly I need all values in $hometeamarray to be replaced by a more correct version stored in $output-> ALIGNED. Before the first loop the $hometeamarray is empty.

Comment: @McClaud then the problem is that $hometeamarray is empty. This means that you did not succeed in filling it up.

Comment: @McClaud what's $i and what is its initial value before entering into the first loop? How many items do you have in $fixturesarray?

Comment: The $fixturesarray contains 648 items. It’s a table with 72 rows and 9 columns and I create the array with DOMDocument. Then I split it into 8 different arrays (one I don’t need) using modulus. I guess the $i is the items - or in this example 1/9 of them. $i has no initial value as it is now...

Comment: Is the $hometeamarray empty? If I make a print_r after the second loop - then it’s there... Hmmm

Comment: @McClaud if it is not empty, then what is in it?

Comment: Well it's there but it was filled with hidden symbols as mentioned by @splash58. Actually I've changed tactics and succeeded. I used the array_chunk function in stead of modulus and everything became much easier. Thank you for all the very inspiring input. That made way to success.  :)

Comment: @McClaud modulo should work. I did not test it, but I wonder whether the lack of initialization for $i caused your problem or not.

Comment: @McClaud without knowing the exact values you have I can only guess. Since it is a table with rows and columns, when you foreach it, the value might be an array and you will end up with an array of arrays. Looking for a string in an array of arrays will not find your string, even if it is present in one or more of the inner arrays. If you provide more exact details about your input, then I can give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
foreach (array_chunk($fixturesarray,9) as $key => $value) {
  $hometeam = $value[4];
  foreach ($xmlteams->children() as $output) { if ($output->OPPONENT == $hometeam) { $hometeamaligned = $output->ALIGNED; }}
}
```

It works like a charm and is much easier to maintain - thanks to array_chunk.